# I get an error 'cannot be resolved to a type' when trying to create a basic tic tac toe game on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a basic Tic Tac Toe game on Eclipse using buttons.  I've only had one class on computer programming but I like it and am trying to learn by doing some basic game design.  I found a YouTube video on how to create tic tac toe as a two person game, not against the computer, and followed it pretty much exactly but still got an error: 'cannot be resolved to a type'.  I know 'cannot be resolved to a type' is usually when something is either miss spelled, or is missing a capital letter or something, but if that is the case I cant find it.  If anyone can help me figure why I'm having this error I would very much appreciate it.

```
package ticTacToe;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridLayout;


public class ticTacToe extends JFrame{
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
XOButton buttons[]=new XOButton[9];
```

My problem is at XOButton above, at both instances of XOButton it shows the error 'XOButton cannot be resolved to a type'.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ticTacToe();

}
public ticTacToe()
{
    super("ticTacToe");
    setSize(400,400);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        buttons[i]=new XOButton();
        panel.add(buttons[i]);
    }
    add(panel);
    setVisible(true);
}
}
```

I also get the error every time I call XOButton or buttons.  I have the class XOButton here:

```
package XOButton;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class XOButton extends JButton implements ActionListener{
ImageIcon X,O;
byte value=0;

/*
 * 0:nothing
 * 1:x
 * 2:O
 */

public XOButton()
{
    X=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("x.png"));
    O=new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("o.png"));
    this.addActionListener(this);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    value++;
    value%=3;
    switch(value)
    {
    case 0:
        setIcon(null);
        break;
    case 1:
        setIcon(X);
        break;
    case 2:
        setIcon(O);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After i reviewed everything is working fine in my IDE , check your imports and class name.
I'll attach the working source code that i used from your post.

**tictacktoe class**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
```

public class ticTacToe extends JFrame{

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
XOButton buttons[]=new XOButton[9];



public ticTacToe()
{

    super("ticTacToe");

    System.out.println("TICK TACK TOE CLASS");

    setTitle("GAME");
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    setSize(390,390);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    panel.setBackground(Color.black);
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        buttons[i]=new XOButton();
        panel.add(buttons[i]);
    }
    add(panel);

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new ticTacToe();

}
}
```

**XObutton class**